# glDraw* returning GL_INVALID_ENUM

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I'm trying to render some objects in OpenGL, but even though I call `glDrawElements` with the right mode, it still gives me a `GL_INVALID_ENUM`. This is the call log, as recorded by AMD's CodeXL, from setup to rendering:

```
glBindVertexArray(1) 

... creating shaders/programs and getting uniform locations ...

# the vertex buffer
glGenBuffers(1, 0x008A945C) 
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 1) 
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 96, 0x008A94A0, GL_STATIC_DRAW) 

# the element index buffer
glGenBuffers(1, 0x008A9460) 
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 2) 
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 96, 0x008A9508, GL_STATIC_DRAW) 

glClearColor(0.12, 0.63999999, 0.55000001, 1) 
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) 


glEnableVertexAttribArray(0) 
glUseProgram(1)

glUniformMatrix4fv(0, 1, FALSE, ... MVP Matrix ...)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 1) 
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, FALSE, 0, 0x00000000) 
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 2) 


glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, 24, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0x00000000) # GL_INVALID_ENUM here <----


glUseProgram(0)
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0) 
wglSwapBuffers(0x09011214)
```

I've already tried swapping `glDrawElements` by `glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4)` (with the right parameters) and it still gives me the same error. What could be causing this? CodeXL seems pretty sure the error is raised exactly at the draw call, not before.

Comment: because your opengl version doesn't support gl_quads, change to triangles

Comment: How are you creating the context? Using core profile?

Comment: yep, it was the core profile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because `GL_QUADS` has been deprecated in OpenGL 3, see the documentation for [`glDrawArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glDrawElements.xhtml).

You can either:

1. Draw triangles (recommended).
2. Create your opengl context using a [compatiblity profile](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts). (How to do this exactly depends on what you are using to create the context in the first place, SDL, glfw, etc.)